# SQL How to Decode a column by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tab_1` with 3 columns `seller_name`, `id_seller`, `id_buyer`  and i want to show another column named `buyer_name` witch corresponding to `id_buyer`.

The seller can be also buyer and that's why they have the same `id`

```
|  corresponding code |
-----------------------
     abc = 1005
     ddd = 1009
     ccc = 1006
     aaa = 1002
     zzp = 1186
     tyu = 1001
```

---

```
tab_1:

|  seller_name   | id_seller | id_buyer|
-----------------|----------------------
|  abc           | 1005      | 1006    |
|  ddd           | 1009      | 1186    |
|  ccc           | 1006      | 1001    |
|  ccc           | 1006      | 1002    |
|  ddd           | 1009      | 1006    |
|  tyu           | 1001      | 1186    |
```

The results i want is shown bellow:

```
|  seller_name   | id_seller |buyer_name| id_buyer|
-----------------|---------------------------------
|  abc           | 1005      |  ccc     | 1006    |
|  ddd           | 1009      |  zzp     | 1186    |
|  ccc           | 1006      |  tyu     | 1001    |
|  ccc           | 1006      |  aaa     | 1002    |
|  ddd           | 1009      |  ccc     | 1006    |
|  tyu           | 1001      |  zzp     | 1186    |
```

Comment: corresponding code is your table?

Comment: is not a table is an explanation to understand the corresponding between id and name

Comment: What about ZZP? Because ZZP is not present in your seller list??

Comment: is not a condition to be on seller list, it is only in buyer list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    create table #a

    ( buyer_name varchar(50), id_buyer int
    )
    insert into #a values
        ('abc',1005),
        ('ddd',1009),
        ('ccc',1006),
        ('aaa',1002),
        ('zzp',1186),
        ('tyu',1001)


        create table #b
        (

          seller_name varchar(50),   id_seller  int, id_buyer int
          )
          insert into #b values

     ('abc',1005,1006),   
     ('ddd',1009,1186),   
     ('ccc',1006,1001),   
     ('ccc',1006,1002),   
     ('ddd',1009,1006),   
     ('tyu',1001,1186) 

     select seller_name,id_seller,buyer_name,a.id_buyer from #a a join 
      #b b on a.id_buyer=b.id_buyer


or 

SELECT 
    seller.seller_name, seller.id_seller, isnull(person.name,seller.seller_name) AS buyer_name, seller.id_buyer 
FROM 
    #b seller 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT seller_name AS name, id_seller AS id FROM #b) person ON 
        seller.id_buyer = person.id
```

Comment: Read @marius Comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a self join on `tab_1`.

```
SELECT 
    seller.seller_name, seller.id_seller, person.name AS buyer_name, seller.id_buyer 
FROM 
    tab_1 seller 
    -- workout the corresponding code table
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT seller_name AS name, id_seller AS id FROM tab_1) person ON 
        seller.id_buyer = person.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cross apply` to get list. If you want to see the buyuer codes which will not present in seller list use `Outer Apply` Instead of `cross apply`. I suggest you to maintain corresponding code in a table since buyer may not present in seller list column.

```
 select DISTINCT t1.seller_name,id_seller,id_buyer,a.seller_name
    from 
    #table1 t1 cross apply
    (
    select seller_name from #table1  t2 where  t1.id_buyer=t2.id_seller
    )a
```

Answer (score 0):

you should join table_1 with it self. Here i have used left join as one buyer id is not available in your records.

```
select a.seller_name,a.id_seller,a.id_buyer,b.seller_name
from tab_1 a
left join tab_1 b on a.id_buyer=b.id_seller
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "SELF JOIN "

The following link would help [self join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm)